# Perspective Camera does not change view when moved

Tags: camera, light

I have a perspective camera, aligned with the model on the X Y Z axis but moved some distance away from the model in an attempt to fit the whole model in the camera view.  But moving the camera does not change anything.

Also, I have a lamp which is not intense enough to show the model properly but increasing the luminance makes no difference.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I wasn't being aggressive enough with the luminance.  I increased the power setting to 5000 and that worked.

Ditto with the camera - I moved it a long way back and the model image then fitted in the camera window.

It would help if Blender provided a range for these settings - you might expect to double the luminance to get a better view, but not to increase it 5,000 fold!

Comment: Most likely you are dealing with a model that is huge, unfortunatelty you provide no information whatsoever about your scene. It is recommended to create objects in real world scale. It makes sense that lights that are too distant need to be way brighter than usual.

Comment: Its not a huge scale.  It is real-world scale for the viewer.  It is just text for a headline so the text is about 1.75cm tall in the web viewer.  As for the lamp, moving the lamp closer made no difference.  Its distance from the model is dictated by the camera and teh lamp is just above it.